# Put different "schemas" into same MongoDB collection

Tags: python, performance, mongodb

TLDR; Are there drawbacks to putting two different types of documents into the same collection to save a round-trip to the database?

So I have documents with children, and a list of keys in the parent referencing the children, and almost whenever we want a parent, we also want the children to come along. The naive way to do this is to fetch the parent, and then get the children using the list of child keys with $IN (in SQL, we would use a join). However, this means making 2 round trips for a fairly frequent operation. We have a few options to improve this, especially since we can retrieve the child keys at the same time as the parent keys:

1. Put the children in the parent document

   While this would play to mongo's strength, we also want to keep this data normalized
2. Pipeline database requests in threads

   Which may or may not improve performance once we factor in the connection pool. It also means dealing with threading in a python app, which isn't terrible, but isn't great.
3. Keep the parent/child documents in the same collection (not embedded)

   This way we can do one query for all the keys at once; this does mean some conceptual overhead in the wrapper for accessing the database, and forcing all indexes to be sparse, but otherwise seems straightforward.

We could profile all these options, but it does feel like someone out there should already have experience with this despite not finding anything online. So, is there something I am missing in my analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll address the three points separately. You should know that it absolutely depends on the situation on what works best. There is no "theoretically correct" answer as it depends on your data store/access patterns.

1. It is always a fairly complex decision on how you store your data. I think the main rule should be "How do I query my data?", and not "We want to have all data normalised". Data normalisation is something you do for a relational database, not for MongoDB. If you almost always query the children with the parent, and you don't have an unbound list of children, then that is how you should store them. Just be aware that a document in MongoDB is limited to 16MB (which is a lot more than you think).
2. Avoid threading. You will just be better off running two queries in sequence, from two different collections. Less complex is a good thing!
3. This works, but it is a fairly ugly way. But then again, ugly isn't always a bad thing if it makes things go a lot faster. I don't quite know how distinct your parent and child documents are of course, so it's a difficult to say whether this is a good solution. A sparse index, which I assume you will do on a specific field depending on whether it is a parent or child, is a good idea. But perhaps you can get away with one index as well. I'd be happy to update your answer after you've shown your suggested schemas.

I would recommend you do some benchmarking, but forget about option 2.

Comment: RE #1 whenever we want a parent, we want the children, but we also want to query the children by themselves, hence the normalization; while we could do sub-document queries, we'd have to put in more work to keep the de-normalized copies in sync across various parents.

Comment: RE #3 actually, merging the main accessor keys wouldn't be hard. The other indicies would have to stay sparse, though. And, the parent/child schema essentially don't share anything in common, if that changes your answer. The ugliness does make me a bit sad, but since I'd wrap it into something sane I can live with it. And yes, benchmarking seems like a good next step.

Comment: Right, in that case, go with the ugly way: #3 — but try it out too! However, even with #1 you can still query the children by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more levels in the hierarchy (also works fine for one level) it is a good choice to have an array of ancestors. This is kind of a trick which is not invented by me of course it was explained in the mongodb Developer course : https://education.10gen.com/courses (this is just a link where you can find the curse i cannot link to the tutorial directly). In this case you have an array of ids which contains at least the node itself  and all the ancestors ids. If you query for a sub-tree you just have to search for the root in the ancestors array.

The documents hold an:

```
{ancestors: [2,7,6]}
```

You query for subtree under node 6:

```
find({ancestors:6})
```

This is nice but in a real world example you usually not query for ids. So you will have two queries one for something meaningful and one for the ids belongs to that.

But if you query for the id at the first step this solution resolves your issue.

I think due to mongodb lots of things depends on the structure of parent-child relation. If there is only one level of lineage there is no really particular reason to store the data separately and in this case the ugly way is the good choice , even more if you likely to have a complex queries (and indexes) over it, use denormalizing.

(You are not really have chance to query for some feature of parents and retrieve children in the same query without denormalizing/embedding) but embed only if you have a really few-few connection and denormalize only if you not duplicate lots of data. Performance with the two queries won't be that bad if you store the children ids in an array (and index it), it is not a really bad idea compare to keep clean the denormalized data or handle the 16MB limit with the embedding.

Comment: The problem in this case with keeping ancestor ids is that the number of parents for a child document can grow without bound, and at least a few children's ancestor sets will eventually run up against the size constraints.

Comment: Embedding does seem straightforward, but it does trade-off with maintenance/synchronization costs, which are harder to profile. Hmm...

Comment: Ancestors arrays ids are only a way up in the tree, so you will only contain one id from one level and if your tree is well balanced (and it is not always true unfortunately) you can store 2^n element with at most n long ancestor arrays assume that you have only 2 children per parent. This is a fair deal and with that you have no chance to reach the size constraints. The biggest array will be the biggest depth in your tree.